# How can I use selenium with python to click on this type of sub menu links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, quora

I tried many things online but I cant find relevant subject in "inspect code" for Quora website. So can someone tell me how can I click this "Copy link" button(Shown in the attached pic) on quora using selenium. PS:You need to be logged into quora to see that button.

[image: "Copy link button"]

Comment: Your code trials ?

Comment: I tried to use driver.find_elements_by_link_text. Iam not able to understand what exactly i need to use because in quora source code iam unable to understand what type of drop down menu that is.

Comment: isn't the `copy link` url the same as the current url?

Comment: No, its different, its ID in <div> is dynamically allocated and only way to locate it is with 'aria label'. Iam trying out the method someone suggested below but Iam still not successful. Will update if Iam successful.

Comment: Does the url look like this one: https://qr.ae/TUtHz9

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is identify the top level div of that element:
eg:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('__w2_wEahGopL52_icon')
button.click()
```

The parent should be in this order roughly:

```
svg -parent-> span (with class name : ui_button_icon) -parent-> **div** (use this div)
```

next is clicking on the copy link button like so:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('CopyToClipboardShareLink')
button.click()
```